# Linq statement with Projection to class THEN GroupBy results in local evaluation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm sending an IQueryable to a method that parses data for jQuery DataTables. It builds the filter from FORM data and creates a LINQ statement with filter, sorting, paging, etc that gets sent back to the page as JSON. I'd like to extend the parser and add Totals to the result set. When I add a GroupBy statement, the query is not evaluated on the server, but locally instead. It will only execute on the server if the original IQueryable has an anonymous projection...

This is a .Net Core 2.1 website. I know in the past GroupBy could not be executed locally but it does at 2.1. I've tried projection with a class and to an anonymous type, and it only works properly with an anonymous type. I really need to be able to do this with a class.

The following iQueryable gets sent to the parser:

```
var query = Context.InvoiceHeaders
     .AsNoTracking()
     .Where(x=>x.Slsno.Equals("13"))
     .Select(x => new InvoiceHeaderSummary()
     {
         SalesNumber = x.Slsno,
         OrderNumber = x.Ordnum,
         ItemAmount = x.Itmamt,
         SpecialChargeAmount = x.Sc1amt,
         TaxAmount = x.Taxamt,
         InvoiceTotal = x.Invamt
     })

var parser = new Parser<InvoiceHeaderSummary>(Request.Form, query);
```

I'm trying to extend the parser by adding a List of totals to the output. But since I'm sending in an IQueryable with a class projection (InvoiceHeaderSummary), it doesn't execute on the server. I get the warning about it being evaluated locally:

```
var totalList = query
     .GroupBy(i => 1)
     .Select(g => new
     {
          TotalInvoice = g.Sum(i => i.InvoiceTotal)
     })
     .ToList();
```

I tried creating the entire LINQ method inline and it DOES run properly (notice I'm using an anonymous projection prior to the GroupBy rather than InvoiceHeaderSummary class):

```
var query = Context.InvoiceHeaders
     .AsNoTracking()
     .Where(x=>x.Slsno.Equals("13"))
     .Select(x => new
     {
         SalesNumber = x.Slsno,
         OrderNumber = x.Ordnum,
         ItemAmount = x.Itmamt,
         SpecialChargeAmount = x.Sc1amt,
         TaxAmount = x.Taxamt,
         InvoiceTotal = x.Invamt
     })
     .GroupBy(i => 1)
     .Select(g => new
     {
          TotalInvoice = g.Sum(i => i.InvoiceTotal)
     })
     .ToList();
```

Is there a way to properly write this so it runs optimally??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently one of the EF Core 2.x query translation defects / bugs.

The only workaround I've found is to use the `GroupBy` overload with element selector and select the data you want to aggregate into anonymous type:

```
var totalList = query
     .GroupBy(i => 1, i => new { i.InvoiceTotal }) // <--
     .Select(g => new
     {
          TotalInvoice = g.Sum(i => i.InvoiceTotal)
     })
     .ToList();
```